# mi app de radio se detiene a los 3 minutos de reproducir la radio Radio Streaming

Tags: app, radiobutton, radio, radiogroup

buenas cree una aplicación android en androidstudio para mi radio online, y sucede que la cree con botones y un webview para el reproductor de la radio, y este al pasar 3 o 7 minutos se detiene la música nose si alguien me podría ayudar como solucionar este tema, he intentado con un servicio para que funcionara en segundo plano pero no me funciono el código nose si habrá otra opción para este problema

Comment: al parecer es por un problema de ahorror de energia, en el cual el celular inactiva el audio. Aca puedes encontrar todo https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/radio$20stop$20play%7Csort:date/mitappinventortest/Tz-h1ZysGxY/RwjxHNH9AgAJ

Comment: Aún tienes este problema Nicolás. Yo lo resolví usando Services + Exoplayer (Android Library). Además usar Foreground service te ayuda a escuchar sin que se pause cada cierto tiempo. Puede se Saludos.

Comment: Mi APP de radio se detiene la reproducción pasados 10 minutos exactos y no se como solucionarlo. la he creado en android studio y en el simulador de va bien, pero cuando la instalas en el móvil se detiene a los 10 minutos y hay que volver a darle al play. Necesito ayuda.

Comment: @LuisSerranoGarcía Hola Luis, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad no es un problema de ahorro de energía, es una característica del sistema operativo para ahorro de recursos. Cuando se trata de apagar la pantalla cualquier reproducción se detiene.

Como solución define la bandera [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)  en el método onCreate() de tu Activity.

> [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) Indicador de ventana: siempre que esta
> ventana sea visible para el usuario, mantenga la pantalla del
> dispositivo encendida y brillante.

Ejemplo:

```
  public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
```

De esta forma la reproducción de tu streaming no se detendrá a menos que tu mismo detengas la reproducción, o cierres tu dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Jorgesys pero esto no lo ha solucionado. Lo que ocurre es que la reproducción se detiene pasados unos segundos o unos minutos dependiendo de cada móvil y hay que darle al play para reanudarla, pero entonces se escucha con pequeños saltos y hay que cerrar la app y volverla abrir para que se escuche bien. Puedes verlo tu mismo si te la descargas aquí: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.losmegaexitos&hl=es_419&gl=US
Estoy tan desesperado que si alguien me lo arregla le pagaría para que lo hiciera.